# Problems of Z3 (version 4.3): Output of Real value is not round automatically

Tags: z3

Please help me to solve this problem, I have tried various ways but not successful.

In the site: http://rise4fun.com/Z3

when solving this formula:

```
(declare-const a Real)
(assert (= a (/ 5 2)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

the result is

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun a () Real
    (/ 5.0 2.0))
)
```

The answer is **(/ 5.0 2.0)** which is not a round value. (I need 2.5)

In the old version of Z3 (version 3.2), with the same above formula: the answer is **2.5** (that is what I need)

**Is there anyone know how to config Z3 (version 4.3) to get the same answer as its old version?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following code

```
(declare-const a Real)
(assert (= a (/ 5 2)))
(check-sat)
(set-option :pp-decimal true)
(get-model)
```

and the output is

```
sat 
(model 
  (define-fun a () Real 
  2.5) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much!
Could you tell me where can I find "set-option" configuration like this?

Comment: Hi, I am not an expert on Z3 and I do not know how to use the "set-option" at general.  I expect that Leonardo de Moura will give us more information about it.  All the best.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to hide all warnings and errors?

if Z3 cannot solve, it returns "unsat". <br/>
if other errors, return "null"